# clang astparser has problems with stdlib in analyzed files (undeclared identifier __builtin_swap32, va_list and so on)

Tags: c++, include, clang, std, abstract-syntax-tree

i try to write a astparser for a large c++-project with lots of template functions and structs, as well as template functor usage. however i'm stuck now. the first problem was that my astparser could not find stdlib.h. this problem i've solved by providing additional system dependent include paths to stdlib.h and other system and c++ headers. however, now i get these error messages, when my parser is running:

```
In file included from source/real_test.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7.2/tr1/stdarg.h:32:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7.2/tr1/cstdarg:32:
/usr/include/c++/4.7.2/cstdarg:56:11: error: no member named 'va_list' in the global namespace
using ::va_list;
    ~~^

/usr/include/bits/byteswap.h:47:10: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_bswap32'<br>
return __builtin_bswap32 (__bsx);
     ^
/usr/include/bits/byteswap.h:111:10: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_bswap64'
return __builtin_bswap64 (__bsx);
     ^


In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7.2/fstream:40:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7.2/istream:40:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7.2/ios:39:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7.2/iosfwd:42:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7.2/bits/postypes.h:42:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7.2/cwchar:46:
/usr/include/wchar.h:614:9: error: unknown type name '__gnuc_va_list'
                  __gnuc_va_list __arg)
                  ^
/usr/include/wchar.h:621:8: error: unknown type name '__gnuc_va_list'
                 __gnuc_va_list __arg)
                 ^
/usr/include/wchar.h:627:9: error: unknown type name '__gnuc_va_list'
                  __gnuc_va_list __arg)
                  ^
/usr/include/wchar.h:691:8: error: unknown type name '__gnuc_va_list'
                 __gnuc_va_list __arg)
                 ^
/usr/include/wchar.h:698:7: error: unknown type name '__gnuc_va_list'
                __gnuc_va_list __arg)
                ^
/usr/include/wchar.h:703:8: error: unknown type name '__gnuc_va_list'
                 __gnuc_va_list __arg)
```

and so on.....

i'm not sure how to solve it. i think the problem is even that the parser knows where it can find the required c++ headers, it does not include other headers which define MACROS, like _STDLIB_H required by the previous ones. Can anyone please help me.

With kind regards
Max

Comment: My GUESS is that your astparser either doesn't include builtin functions that are normally providied by clang and/or GCC, or is missing -D options normally set by the compiler. You can see what is defined by the compiler using `clang -E -dM -xc /dev/null` (same works for clang++, gcc and g++ - for c++, use `-xc++` - you may need to apply `-c-std=C++11` or similar too)

Comment: Right `__builtin_*` are functions provided by the compiler. You can find a list of them in include/clang/Basic/Builtins.def in the clang source directory. A `Builtin::Context` is passed to the `ASTContext` on construction. But presumably this either isn't done correctly in your case...

Comment: well by providing additional include files to further c++ headers the astparser doesn't compain about any unknown type names, as before. however i've still the undeclared identifier __builtin_bswap(32/64), __builtin_clz, __builtin_memcmp and so on. and a dump of the first translationunitdecl for the analyzed project, contains those -TypedefDecl 0xa9c630 <<invalid sloc>> <invalid sloc> implicit __int128_t '__int128'        and so on. i guess my astparser really misses some MACROS provided by -D option or some further builtin functions. I'll try to find out using your suggestions

Comment: in builtins.def in clang include directory: i've the right builtins defined: BUILTIN(__builtin_bswap16, "UsUs", "nc")
BUILTIN(__builtin_bswap32, "UiUi", "nc")
BUILTIN(__builtin_bswap64, "ULLiULLi", "nc")

Comment: Yes, I expect all builtins are present in the Builtins.def - but it would seem that the astparser of yours doesn't make use of them. And likewise for some builtin types, as well. Some of this depends on the target you are building for, so you may need to look at that.